# Inverse of ignore_attribute_changes_of in Sunspot Searchable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

In Sunspot Solr I have a model `Contact` that I index in Solr. The `Contact` model has many attributes, but I index two of them, `:name` and `:email`. To prevent that every time a field changed in a `Contact` we contact Solr, I use `:ignore_attribute_changes_of` on the searchable.

In fact, I just want to update my index when I change `:name` or `:email`. I do that like this:

```
fields = (Contact.attribute_names - ["name", "email"]).map{|o| o.to_sym}

searchable :ignore_attribute_changes_of => fields do
  text :name
  text :email
end
```

This seems the wrong way around to me. Is there a way to tell Sunspot searchable to *only* update on a change of certain attributes? That is, is there an inverse of `ignore_attribute_changes_of` or is there a reason that is built this way?

Comment: I guess they just didn't think about it. Why don't you try to open an issue on https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot and see what they say?

Answer (score -2):

i guess, you can disable auto-indexing in model and move index action to controller in this way

## in model

```
searchable :auto_index => false do
  text :name
  text :email
end
```

## in controller

```
def update
  ...
  if @contact.name_changed?||@contact.email_changed?
    Sunspot.index(@contact)
  end
end
```

Comment: or even you can try to use `:auto_index => check_if_name_or_email_changed` instead of `:auto_index => false`  
  
    `def check_if_name_or_email_changed  
       name_changed?||email_changed?  
    end`  
  
but this solution i didn't check